# locating nng glassfish logs to find out why i am unable to open Jaguar incontrol touch updater

Tags: http, status

/YOUR_GLASSFISH_INSTALL/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/

http status 500 error

load update from website

Jaguar Incontrol Touch Updater